# Ibus-Avro prints Arabic characters in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: language-support, ibus, input-method, 17.04, ibus-avro

I updated my Ubuntu to 17.04 today and now `ibus-avro` prints arabic characters. It was working fine before. I tried the bn to us trick as suggested on the website but that's of no use. It still prints Arabic characters instead of Bengali.